# why is there no extension folder under php

Tags: php

I compiled PHP but there is no "extensions" folder. I do not see any configuration flags related to extensions. Is the extension folder manually added after or when I install an extension.

Comment: Maybe its called `ext`

Answer (score 0):

The following website had the modules I needed: https://pecl.php.net/

Specifically, apc.so, geoip.so, imagick.so and redis.so

On the OLD system I need to find which version was being used so I was able to install on the NEW system. The following showed me the version for imagick.

`/usr/local/php54/bin/php --re imagick | head -1`

Then I download the package to the new system using wget.

`wget https://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.4.1.tgz`

Uncompress...

`tar zxvf imagick-3.4.1.tgz`

CD to the directory

`cd imagick-3.4.1`

Run the following which gives the configure file.

`/usr/local/php54/bin/phpize`

Configure

`configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php54/bin/php-config`

Followed by make, make test and make install.

After doing the make install you'll see something similar to the following.

`Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/
Installing header files:          /usr/local/php54/include/php/`

The extensions directory is created for you.